# VB.net OOP How to call method in namespace from FrmMain

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oop

I am trying to make a VB.net WinForm-application that connects to a database.
I have a class with the specs to make a database-connection (Intersystems Cache).  The database isn't important, the principile does.

How do I call the methods in this class form the FrmMain?
I can't get my head around it.

Thanks

```
Imports Test.NSConnection.Connection

Public Class FrmMain
    Private Sub FrmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'how do I call the DoOpenConnectionCache?

    End Sub
End Class
```

and:

```
Imports InterSystems.Data.CacheClient
Imports InterSystems.Data.CacheTypes
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Namespace NSConnection
    Public Class Connection
        Private _cacheString As String
        Public Property cacheString() As String
            Get
                Return _cacheString
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _cacheString = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _cnCache As CacheADOConnection
        Public Property cnCache() As CacheADOConnection
            Get
                Return _cnCache
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As CacheADOConnection)
                _cnCache = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub SetConnectionString()
            
            Dim _cacheString As String = "Server = localhost; Port = ****; Namespace = ****; User ID= **** ; Password= ****;"
            Dim _cnCache = New CacheConnection(_cacheString)
        End Sub

        Public Sub DoOpenConnectionCache()
            Try
                If _cnCache.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    _cnCache.Open()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub

        Public Sub DoCloseConnectionCache()
            Try
                If _cnCache.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    _cnCache.Close()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an object of type `Connection`, then you can do it like this:

```
Dim Connection1 As Connection = New Connection()
```

and call its method `DoOpenConnectionCache`